# Workflow with User Input

Tags: apache-hop

Newbie to Apache-Hop.

Is it possible to create blocking actions (for a workflow) that wait for a User input? A very basic use-case will be Supervisor-Approval. More advanced will be additional data input.

Is this possible?

Backgound - I'm browsing through Apache projects suitable to develop business workflows.